# error: Font \TU/LatinModernRoman(0)/bx/n/10=LatinModernRoman

Tags: errors, luatex, miktex, miktex2.9, luacode

Everything was working fine in my main document before trying to embed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330494/2288) in my code. However, I don't quite understand the steps needed to resolve this according to [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288036/2288).

The error message is

> Font \TU/LatinModernRoman(0)/bx/n/10=LatinModernRoman/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;-liga; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \section*{Editor Comment}

P.S. I am compiling on Win 10 using MikTeX 2.9.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Cambria Math}
\setmainfont[
Ligatures={NoRequired,
    NoCommon,
    NoContextual}
]{Latin Modern Roman}


\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\biboptions{square,numbers,sort&compress}
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8\dimexpr(\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2\relax}
\usepackage[textwidth=\marginparwidth]{todonotes}


\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@todonotes@owner{default}
\define@key{todonotes}%
{owner}{\def\@todonotes@owner{#1}}


\newtoggle{ownerdefault}
\newtoggle{ownerB}
\newtoggle{ownerEditor}


\newcommand\stR[2]{% 1st reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=default,
    author=Reviewer \#1,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=blue!20%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{blue}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\ndR[2]{% 2nd reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=B,
    author=Reviewer \#2,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=red!50!white%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\stEditor[2]{% editor comment
    \todo[%
    owner=Editor,
    author=Editor,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=red!50!white% color of margin note
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}% color of comment text


\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
    \if@todonotes@colorinlistoftodos%
    \addtocontents{tdo}
    {%
        \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
        {%
            \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\protect\fcolorbox{\@todonotes@currentbordercolor}%
                {\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}%
                {\protect\textcolor{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{o}}%
                \ \@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
        }{}%
    }%
    \else%
    \addtocontents{tdo}
    {%
        \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
        {%
            \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
        }{}%
    }%
    \fi}%

\makeatother
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
    function sort_tdo (jobname)
    local lines = {}
    -- read the lines in table 'lines'
    for line in io.lines(jobname) do
    table.insert(lines, line)
    end
    -- sort
    table.sort(lines)
    -- write all the lines
    file=io.open(jobname.."sorted", "w") 
    io.output(file) 
    for i, l in ipairs(lines) do io.write(l, "\n") 
    end
    io.close(file)
    end 
\end{luacode*}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{\directlua{sort_tdo("\jobname.tdo")}}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\sectionbookmark}[1][]{%
    \bookmark[%
    level=section,%
    dest=\@currentHref,%
    #1%
    ]%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}




\toggletrue{ownerEditor}
\section*{Editor Comment}
\sectionbookmark{Editor Comment}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdosorted}{}

\toggletrue{ownerdefault}
\togglefalse{ownerEditor}
\section*{Reviewer \#1 Comments}
\sectionbookmark{Reviewer \#1 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdosorted}{}

\toggletrue{ownerB}
\togglefalse{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewer \#2 Comments}
\sectionbookmark{Reviewer \#2 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdosorted}{}

\togglefalse{ownerB}
\makeatletter \@starttoc{tdo}\makeatother % to trigger the creation of the list

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\stR{1st}{reviewer} some text

\stEditor{1st}{editor} some text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LuaLaTeX, the global variable `file` is used to access the `file` library from `lualibs`. You code changes `file`, therefore the library can no longer be accessed which breaks luaotfload.

You can fix this by making `file` local:

Instead of

```
file=io.open(jobname.."sorted", "w")
```

write

```
local file=io.open(jobname.."sorted", "w")
```

Also your document changes Lua's default output files using `io.output(...)`. That's also breaking all other Lua code trying to print to the terminal by using the default output. Instead, you can replace `io.write` by `file:write`.

This leads to the document:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Cambria Math}
\setmainfont[
Ligatures={NoRequired,
    NoCommon,
    NoContextual}
]{Latin Modern Roman}


\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\biboptions{square,numbers,sort&compress}
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8\dimexpr(\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2\relax}
\usepackage[textwidth=\marginparwidth]{todonotes}


\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@todonotes@owner{default}
\define@key{todonotes}%
{owner}{\def\@todonotes@owner{#1}}


\newtoggle{ownerdefault}
\newtoggle{ownerB}
\newtoggle{ownerEditor}


\newcommand\stR[2]{% 1st reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=default,
    author=Reviewer \#1,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=blue!20%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{blue}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\ndR[2]{% 2nd reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=B,
    author=Reviewer \#2,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=red!50!white%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\stEditor[2]{% editor comment
    \todo[%
    owner=Editor,
    author=Editor,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=red!50!white% color of margin note
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}% color of comment text


\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
    \if@todonotes@colorinlistoftodos%
    \addtocontents{tdo}
    {%
        \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
        {%
            \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\protect\fcolorbox{\@todonotes@currentbordercolor}%
                {\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}%
                {\protect\textcolor{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{o}}%
                \ \@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
        }{}%
    }%
    \else%
    \addtocontents{tdo}
    {%
        \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
        {%
            \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
        }{}%
    }%
    \fi}%

\makeatother
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
    function sort_tdo (jobname)
    local lines = {}
    -- read the lines in table 'lines'
    for line in io.lines(jobname) do
    table.insert(lines, line)
    end
    -- sort
    table.sort(lines)
    -- write all the lines
    local file=io.open(jobname.."sorted", "w") 
    for i, l in ipairs(lines) do file:write(l, "\n") 
    end
    file:close()
    end 
\end{luacode*}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{\directlua{sort_tdo("\jobname.tdo")}}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\sectionbookmark}[1][]{%
    \bookmark[%
    level=section,%
    dest=\@currentHref,%
    #1%
    ]%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}




\toggletrue{ownerEditor}
\section*{Editor Comment}
\sectionbookmark{Editor Comment}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdosorted}{}

\toggletrue{ownerdefault}
\togglefalse{ownerEditor}
\section*{Reviewer \#1 Comments}
\sectionbookmark{Reviewer \#1 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdosorted}{}

\toggletrue{ownerB}
\togglefalse{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewer \#2 Comments}
\sectionbookmark{Reviewer \#2 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdosorted}{}

\togglefalse{ownerB}
\makeatletter \@starttoc{tdo}\makeatother % to trigger the creation of the list

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\stR{1st}{reviewer} some text

\stEditor{1st}{editor} some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this great help. It would be great if you don't mind adding an answer to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330485/2288) so that nobody would face this clash later.

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but I would be highly grateful if you could consider taking a look at [my lualatex related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539020/2288).