# Symbols from `stmaryrd` not working any more - No error message

Tags: texstudio, stmaryrd

I compile with LuaLaTeX.

All of a sudden, the symbols of the `stmaryrd` package just do not appear any more.

For example if there is $\llbracket$, the file compiles fine without errors but in the output, the command is completely ignored.

Even with a minimum file with just `documentclass`, `usepackage` and `begin/end{document}`, none of the symbols of the package works.

**There is no error message.**

I thought of a `MikTeX` issue, except it's a brand new install. Uninstalling/reinstalling the package didn't help.

So all I can think of is it's a bug in the latest TexStudio version 4.4.1 which is very young (less than a month). Something's not right with this version. I will try downgrading.

**Edit**:
Downgrading to v4.2.3 does nothing.

Maybe an encoding issue? I'm on UTF-8, normal I guess.

**Edit**: I tried to compile with PdfLaTeX and it worked.
**Now it works again** with LuaLaTeX, with any file.

I don't understand. I lost like 2 hours on this, with a deadline tomorrow.

Comment: Check this suggestion, hope it will helps you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287312/font-not-loadable-metric-data-not-found-or-bad

Comment: Thanks, but as I said it works now. Only, it remains a mystery...

Comment: It's not a mystery, hope you are using the package `'stmaryrd` first time, so while running either `latex` or `pdflatex`, all the necessary font supporting files are created and then it will supports by all types of `TeX` like `XeLaTeX`, `LuaLaTeX`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Note that this is not exactly the same thing as the other post, as absolutely no error message would hint the nature of the problem.